# How to control and test "invalid value encountered in..." error?

Tags: python, numpy

I have enountered a problem about **invalid value...** which is simple, but tricky in Python.
How can I control or avoid this message by not loosing the meaning of the function(values) in large loops, for example, `+/-inf`, `nan`, etc?

I put a test function as an example which is challenging me:

```
import numpy as np

def test_func(t1, t2):
    return t1**t2

def main():
    # test values
    t1 = np.array([0.0, 2., 1., -1., -.00000000000000000000021])
    t2 = np.array([0.0, 1.12, -3., -2., -.00000000000000000000021])
    print [test_func(i,j) for i in t1 for j in t2]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "__main__", line 2
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars

Warning (from warnings module):
File "__main__", line 2
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
[1.0, 0.0, inf, inf, inf, 1.0, 2.1734697250521164, 0.125, 0.25, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, nan, -1.0, 1.0, nan, 1.0, nan, -1.079796998164345e+65, 2.2675736961451244e+43, nan]
```

**Additionally:**

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
```

I read **exception** conditions, but I could not find the best way for the problem.

Comment: Are you asking how to supress warnings? http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings

Comment: Actually, I was using that `test_func` to calculate something which is part of the huge process, but, when error occures I have no idea how to handle with this situation.. That's what I meant.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For controlling numpy's error messages, use [numpy.seterr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html).

I'd recommend using it within a context, so you can easily control exactly where it takes effect.  E.g.:

```
class NumpySeterrContext(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs
    def __enter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.old_settings = numpy.seterr(**self.kwargs)
    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        numpy.seterr(**self.old_settings)

with NumpySeterrContext(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
    print [test_func(i,j) for i in t1 for j in t2]
```

Caveat: I think `seterr` is not thread safe.

Comment: there is also np.errstate on newer numpy versions, you don't have to write it yourself.

Comment: @seberg, I think, I could not describe the problem well enough. What I wanted to do is  just to prevent these errors when it is encountered as well as to change the `nan` or `inf` into `0` or constant values.. How can I do that?